# Windows, Tex Live 2011 multind entries not added to the Index

Tags: indexing, subdividing

This is my code:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX spellcheck = en_GB

\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Brill}
\newfontfamily\lettrinefont{Brill}
\usepackage{multind} 

\makeindex{nominum}
\makeindex{rerum}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\newcommand*{\tg}[1]{\textgreek{#1}}
\usepackage{ledmac}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hanging}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\textheight = 180.5 mm
\textwidth = 108.5 mm
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Afootnote{#2}}}
\newcommand{\oed}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Bfootnote{#2}}}
\footparagraph{A}
\footparagraph{B}
\raggedbottom

\newcommand*{\LeftWidth}{3.0cm}%
\newcommand*{\RightWidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\LeftWidth-2em\relax}%
\newcommand{\AlignedBrace}[2]{%
    \medskip\par\noindent%
    \makebox[\LeftWidth][r]{\text{#1}~}%
    $\left\{~\parbox{\RightWidth}{\strut\textit{#2}\strut}\right.$%
}%

\begin{document}

\pagebreak


\mainmatter

Wyatt\index{nominum}{Wyatt}

\beginnumbering

\pstart

 orator\index{rerum}{orator} is the artificer, the oration\index{rerum}{oration}

\pend
\endnumbering
\printindex{nominum}{Index nominum}
\printindex{rerum}{Index rerum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what is included in `\pend`?  from what's here, it doesn't look like any index entries are generated.  as an aside, you can indicate code either by indenting each line with four spaces, or marking the block with the little box icon that appears when you edit your input.

Comment: I get one entry in `nominum.idx` and two in `rerum.idx`, as expected.

Comment: Are you remembering to run makeindex on nominum.idx and rerum.idx?

Comment: Probably something silly I'm not doing, should I first run makeindex on nominum.idx and rerum.idx and then run xelatex on my main file?

Answer (score 2):

The package `multind` is quite old and unmaintained. It's actually a port from a LaTeX 2.09 style option. It does its job, but is not easily customizable. Perhaps switching to `imakeidx` will make things easier for you: instead of

```
\usepackage{multind} 
\makeindex{nominum}
\makeindex{rerum}
```

you can say

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=nominum,title=Index Nominum,intoc]
\makeindex[name=rerum,title=Index Rerum,intoc]
```

and change the indexing macros to

```
Wyatt\index[nominum]{Wyatt}

...

orator\index[rerum]{orator} is the artificer, the oration\index[rerum]{oration}
```

(notice the brackets instead of the braces).

At the end you'll write

```
\printindex[nominum]
\printindex[rerum]
```

This has some advantages: with the `intoc` option we're telling LaTeX to add an entry in the table of contents. Moreover, MakeIndex will be run automatically, freeing you from the burden of keeping track of this problem.

<sub>Disclosure: I'm one of the authors of `imakeidx`, but since its release it has proved quite useful.</sub>

Comment: Many thanks folks but I've decided to switch to a mac, it should make things easier.